# Sort json based on length of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, sorting

I am trying to sort a feed that I have called in using Jquery.ajax. I'm trying to sort it by the number of values in an array within the feed.

For example, in this feed, I want to sort it by # of NFL teams in descending, so it would be re-sorted to California, New Jersey, Massachusetts:

```
[
   {
      "title":"New Jersey",
      "NFLteams":[
         {
            "Name":"Jets",
            "Conference":"AFC",
         },
         {
            "Name":"Giants",
            "Conference":"NFC",
         }
         ]
   },
   {
      "title":"Massachusetts",
      "NFLteams":[
         {
            "Name":"Patriots",
            "Conference":"AFC",
         }
         ]
   },
   {
      "title":"California",
      "NFLteams":[
         {
            "Name":"Raiders",
            "Conference":"AFC",
         },
         {
            "Name":"49ers",
            "Conference":"NFC",
         },
         {
            "Name":"Chargers",
            "Conference":"AFC",
         }
         ]
   }
]
```

I've tried code like this (from this thread [Sorting an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects)), but it doesn't work (even if I make it NFLteams.length):

```
   var sort_by = function(field, reverse, primer){
   var key = function (x) {return primer ? primer(x[field]) : x[field]};

   return function (a,b) {
      var A = key(a), B = key(b);
      return ( (A < B) ? -1 : ((A > B) ? 1 : 0) ) * [-1,1][+!!reverse];                  
   }
   }
   data.sort(sort_by('NFLteams', false, function(a){return a.toUpperCase()}))
```

Any suggestions on how I can sort by the # of values in the array? Thanks to anyone who can help or point me in the right direction.

Comment: well, if those values are stored and fetched from DB would be easier to COUNT and compare then sort, just an idea.

Answer (score 4):

Your method seems to work if you use the length property of the array:

```
data.sort(sort_by('NFLteams', false, function(a){return a.length}))
```

See JsBin: http://jsbin.com/eWafEMe/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

Simple function like this will do the trick.

```
data.sort(function(a,b){
     return b.NFLteams.length - a.NFLteams.length;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x9d2J/

Answer (score 1):

in your sort function reverse the comparison to return in descending order:

```
.sort(function(team1, team2) {
    return team2.NFLteams.length - team1.NFLteams.length;
});
```

or multiply the result by -1:

```
.sort(function(team1, team2) {
    return -1 * (team1.NFLteams.length - team2.NFLteams.length);
});
```

See the console output from [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aS5nt/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `underscore's` [`sortBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy):

```
_.sortBy(i, function(team){ return team['NFLteams'].length }).reverse();
```

where `i` is your input array.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kMbsW/